# Google cloud AI platform error in executing job

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

Using python `googleapiclient` API we are creating a job in the AI platform.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import datetime

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
training_inputs = {'scaleTier':'CUSTOM','masterType':'complex_model_m',
        'packageUris':['package_bucket_file_path'],

        'pythonModule':'randomforest_trainer_RUL.train',
        'args':[
                '--trainFilePath', data[0],
                '--trainOutputPath', data[2],
                '--testFilePath', data[1],
                '--testOutputPath', data[3],
                '--target', target_label,
                '--bucket', BUCKET,
                '--expid', experiment_id
        ],
        'region': "region_of_bucket",
        'runtimeVersion':'1.14',
        'pythonVersion':'3.5'}

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d_%H%M%S%f')
job_name = "job_"+experiment_id

## logging information
logging.info("Job Name:{}".format(job_name))
##
api = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials,cache_discovery=False)

project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(PROJECT)
credentials  = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
request = api.projects().jobs().create(body=job_spec, parent=project_id)
```

It was working and I am able to train the model, did the testing and prediction till yesterday.
But all of sudden I'm not able to train the model in AI Platform and the error that I'm getting is

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. \nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  [...]\n  
    File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 810, in ls\n    
    combined_listing = self._ls(path, detail) + self._ls(path + "/", detail)\n  
    File "</root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-12>", line 2, in _ls\n  
    File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 50, in _tracemethod\n    
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 820, in _ls\n    listing = self._list_objects(path)\n  File "</root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-5>", 
    line 2, in _list_objects\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 50, in _tracemethod\nreturn f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 616, in _list_objects\n    listing = self._do_list_objects(path)\n  File "</root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-6>", 
    line 2, in _do_list_objects\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 50, in _tracemethod\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 637, in _do_list_objects\n    maxResults=max_results,\n  File "</root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-2>", 
    line 2, in _call\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 50, in _tracemethod\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 517, in _call\n    validate_response(r, path)\n  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", 
    line 171, in validate_response\n    raise IOError("Forbidden: %s\\n%s" % (path, msg))\nOSError: 
    Forbidden: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/some-storage-bucket/o/\nservice-87XX90XX1XX@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
    does not have serviceusage.services.use access to project 34XX12XX12X.\n\nTo find out more about why your job exited 
    please check the logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=87XX90XX1XX&resource=ml_job%2Fjob_id%2Fjob_5de3592da3c3c541d73389er&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22ml_job%22%0Aresource.labels.job_id%3D%22job_5de3592da3c3c541d73389erce%22
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
service-87XX90XX1XX@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
    does not have serviceusage.services.use access to project 34XX12XX12X
```

Comment: Got exactly the same problem today, turned out this happens because of the new release of gcsfs - it breaks authorization somehow. I rollbacked to  ‘0.5.1’  and now it's working again. Try to do the same, otherwise maybe rollback one of your google dependencies to a previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the exact problem today. As Nick said, it's the GCSFS new release problem. Instead of using `pd.read_csv(gcs_path)` I suggest you to read the CSV file from the bucket directly by Tensorflow GFile Function.

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(gcs_path) as f:
            if(opts):
                df = pd.read_csv(f, opts)
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv(f)
        return df
```

It will allow you to run the job without any breaking.